# Javascript onclick link text change

Tags: javascript, text, hyperlink, onclick

I'm working on a new page and for the mobile version I'm going to make a navigation toggle in order to hide and to show the navigation.

**HTML code :**

```
<div id="toogleNavigation">
    <a onclick="toggle_visibility('nav_header','nav_header_level2');">Navigation Einblenden</a>
</div>
```

**Javascript code :**

```
function toggle_visibility(id, id2) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    var f = document.getElementById(id2);
    if(e.style.display == 'block' || 
       e.style.display == 'block' && 
       f.style.display == 'block') {
        e.style.display = 'none';
        f.style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('toogleNavigation').innerHTML = "Navigation 1einblenden";
    } else {
        e.style.display = 'block';
        f.style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('toogleNavigation').innerHTML = "Navigation 2ausblenden";
    }
}
```

I've tried with :

```
document.getElementById('toogleNavigation').innerHTML = "Navigation 2ausblenden";
```

to change the text in text "Navigation Einblenden" when pressing on the link, but this doesn't work... Does somebody has an idea?

Comment: You're not targeting the anchor, you're targeting the wrapping div element, effectively removing the anchor when you change the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make change like this....
***HTML code***

```
<div id="toogleNavigation">
    <a id="divInner" onclick="toggle_visibility('nav_header','nav_header_level2');">
        Navigation Einblenden
    </a>
</div>
```

And
***JavaScript Code***

```
function toggle_visibility(id, id2) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   var f = document.getElementById(id2);
   if(e.style.display == 'block' ||
      ( e.style.display == 'block' &&            
      f.style.display == 'block' ) ) {
        e.style.display = 'none';
        f.style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('divInner').innerHTML = "Navigation  1einblenden";
      } 
      else {
        e.style.display = 'block';
        f.style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('divInner').innerHTML = "Navigation 2ausblenden";
      }
}
```

This will work for you as **its working fo**

Answer (score 2):

Moved the id from div to the a.

See it working in jsbin http://jsbin.com/eqeheb/5/watch

`<div>   <a  id="toogleNavigation"  onclick="toggle_visibility('nav_header','nav_header_level2');">Navigation Einblenden</a> </div>`

Comment: You will need to click on that.